# Error while trying to display cocoapod module

Tags: swiftui, module, cocoapods

I tried using this module as provided in the description but im getting an error Type "()" cannot conform to "View"

```
import SwiftUI
import Shiny

struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        let shinyView = ShinyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 200))
        shinyView.colors = [.gray, .red, .green, .blue, .gray]
        shinyView.startUpdates() 
        testView.addSubview(shinyView)
    }
}

#Preview {
    test()
}
```

I tried fixing it with existing solutions but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: if `ShinyView` is a SwiftUI `View` you should not hold it in a variable, SwiftUI Views dont work that way. if it is a `UiView` you need a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the way SwiftUI works. If you're using an UIKit view, you have to convert it to SwiftUI with `UIViewRepresentable`.

```swift
import Shiny

struct MyShinyView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ShinyView {
        let shinyView = ShinyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 200))
        shinyView.colors = [.gray, .red, .green, .blue, .gray]
        shinyView.startUpdates()
        return shinyView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ShinyView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Then in SwiftUI file:

```swift
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyShinyView()
    }
}
```